# Facebook account closed, no reason given, no way to appeal given

Tags: facebook, account-recovery, facebook-account

So I try to log in my Facebook account and it appears a message which says "your account is suspended", if you have questions, you can see our frequented questions here. "You don't comply the requisites to use Facebook. This decision is definitive. For security reasons, we can't give aditional information why your account was suspended".

In groups I'm admin of, there were a lot of messages sometimes Facebook sent messages that they removed posts (unapproved by me) which violated the terms of use. I have no idea which reason Facebook could have to suspend my account, but I guess possibly it could be that?

Is there anything which can be done in this situation?

Update: I received a notification to my secondary email, which is weird because all Facebook notifications, including one I received 5 days ago, I receive in my primary email. I saw it by chance. It says I have 180 days to appeal, but when I click the appeal button in the email, it sends me to the login page and I can't login. Since I dont remember the password (they made me change it dozens of times so I had to come with a new one all the time), I tried to reset the password, but there I get the "account is suspended" message again, so I can't reset the password and therefore I can't appeal

Comment: I edited the topic. I'm trying no to invite people to discuss Facebook Terms of Use, but the information I left might be useful for identifying the type of situation and what can you do from there on, if anything

Comment: If I recally correctly, they already did that to me once some years ago, and said "it was a mistake".

Comment: Long story short: In 2023, my Facebook account was suspended, but I couldn't access the Facebook login page using the web browser profile I set up for using Facebook and related stuff. using another web browser profile, I got access to the Facebook login page, and after trying to log in, I got a link to appeal. After I followed the instructions, I got my account unsuspended.

Comment: @Rubén-VolunteerModerator- thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I can access to the login page, but I don't get any link to appeal. They just give me a link which says "the decision is definitive","for security reasons we can't tell you why" and "for knowing more about our policies read here". I went there, no answer given, only explanations of facebook policies, I tried sending a message from there in one of the entries, but since it isnt a link to appeal, I doubt they'll reply back. I'm pretty sure this already happened to me  years ago and they said "it was a mistake" after I complained

Comment: @Rubén-VolunteerModerator- well, now I found what happened, the account was hacked by someone who advertises an AI application through Facebook itself. That application is being shared in all my Facebook pages, should I update this question or open a new one?

Comment: @Pablo Feel free to post your solution as an answer to your question. [Users are encouraged to answer their own questions in SE sites.](/help/self-answer)

Comment: @galacticninja I know, but I dont have an answer yet, I just found my account was hacked and Facebook isnt replying me through any channel, I tried 4 different emails, contact them through social networks, contact them through another facebook account, through contact forms, etc. and the worse part is they are using the pages I had in my account to try to hack other people, and it's quite bad because all my pages added up to almost 4 millions followers

Comment: Facebook is being quite a mess in this case. Aside of not answering people through any means, they approved the publicity of the application of a hacker, who is hacking Facebook users